# Printing getOrgChart

Tags: jquery, svg, orgchart, getorgchart

I am using the getOrgChart library from [here](http://www.getorgchart.com/), and I am trying to print out the entire chart instead of just the visible section. Unfortunately when using the standard libraries print function it will only print out the first section and I can't figure out how to print the entire chart (which is quite wide with around 200 nodes going horizontally). Even if it is across several pages I don't mind.

I have tried a few libraries like svgToPdf, jsPDF and I understand there are server-side alternatives like Phantom but I am unsure on the best way as well as the easiest to get my SVG tags to print fully.

Comment: Why not export to PNG instead? Although, printing the whole chart on a single sheet of paper means that the content has to be sized to fit.

Answer (score 5):

> Enables printing.

Default value: false

```
var orgchart = new getOrgChart($("#id"),{
   enablePrint: true
});
```

Comment: While using "enablePrint: true" does enable printing, it unfortunately does not allow for printing of multi-page charts without additional extensive tweaking. I wonder if anyone has a ready solution for multi-page printing of the charts produced via GetOrgChart?